# How to use hibernate-types JsonStringType with MariaDB?

Tags: json, hibernate, mariadb, hibernate-types

In a previous project we used the [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) `JsonStringType` successfully with MySQL 5.7.21. This works (in Kotlin):

```
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(name = "JSON", typeClass = JsonStringType::class)
)
class SomeEntity {
    // ...

    @Type(type = "JSON")
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "JSON")
    var data: SomeData = SomeData()
}
```

In a new project, we want to do the same, but with MariaDB 10.5.4. With MariaDB, we get the following error on schema validation with `hbm2ddl=validate`:

> SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [data] in table [`some_entity`]; found [longtext (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [json (Types#OTHER)]".

As far as I see, hibernate-types doesn't officially support MariaDB. In MariaDB, [`JSON`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/) is just an alias for `LONGTEXT` with a `CHECK (JSON_VALID(column))` constraint.

It works if we use `columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT"` instead of `columnDefinition = "JSON"`, however, then the `CHECK` constraint won't be generated with `hbm2ddl=create`.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the the best of both worlds? I.e. create the check constraint and pass schema validation?

Answer (score 2):

> It works if we use columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT" instead of columnDefinition = "JSON", however, then the CHECK constraint won't be generated with hbm2ddl=create.

The [`hbm2ddl`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-schema/) tool is fine to generate an initial migration script that you can manually adjust prior to using it for the very first time.

Afterward, you should use [`Flyway`](https://vladmihalcea.com/flyway-database-schema-migrations/) with migration scripts.

Now, the `JsonStringType` should use `Types.VARCHAR`, as indicated by [`JsonStringSqlTypeDescriptor`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/blob/master/hibernate-types-52/src/main/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/type/json/internal/JsonStringSqlTypeDescriptor.java#L19).

If it doesn't work, it might be because the MariaDB Driver maps the JSON column type to `LONGVARCHAR`, behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and see if I can come up with a pull request. We are already using hbm2ddl only in development and for the initial generation. For migration, we use Liquibase.

Comment: That sounds great. If you can send a Pull Request, I could integrate it into the next release.

Comment: I see the same problem - what is the workaround? found [longtext (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [json (Types#VARCHAR)].  my column definition     @Column( columnDefinition = "json" )
 @JsonRawValue

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked. used LONGTEXT instead of json and schmea validation is ok

Comment: Didn't work for me: "found [longtext (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [json (Types#VARCHAR)]". Had to use VARCHAR(16384) <-- must have a max length to survive MariaDB DDL parser + hibernate validator.

Comment: Coming back, we did not find a proper solution, we just settled for using `@Type(type = "JSON") @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")`. That works well enough when you don't need the `CHECK` constraints.